# How to get the value of a hidden input field inside a div that contains the event.target that triggered the event (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a group of li elements, each li element is represented like this :

```
<li class="list"> <!--Parent-->
   <input type="hidden" id="id" value="3"> <!--Child 1-->
   <div class="cd-1">....</div>            <!--Child 2-->
   <div class="cd-2">                      <!--Child 3 (event trigger)-->
      <select class="reset">
         <option value="1">1</option>
         <option value="2">2</option>
      </select>
   </div>
   <div class="cd-3">                      <!--Child 4-->
</li>
```

The js code that i tried :

```
$('.reset').addEventListener('change', function(event) {
            if(event.target.tagName.toLowerCase() == 'select') {
                console.log($('#id').val());
     }
}
```

It returns the input value of the first li element, any ideas on how to access the input inside the li of the select that triggered the event ?
Thanks for your help!

Comment: Show us what you have tried. Also include your event listener code as per [mcve]

Comment: Add that code to the question itself rather than putting it in an unformtted code block. You can edit a question any time to include more clarification details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mixing jQuery methods and vanilla methods like `addEventListener`.
Use one or the other but be consistent

Using jQuery alone you can do something like the following:

```js
$('select.reset').change(function(){
   // `this` is the select the event occurred on
   const hiddenVal = $(this).closest('.list').find('input:hidden').val()
   console.log('Hidden value:',hiddenVal)

})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="list">
   <input type="hidden" id="id" value="3">
   <div class="cd-1">....</div>
   <div class="cd-2">
      <select class="reset">
         <option value="1">1</option>
         <option value="2">2</option>
      </select>
   </div>
   <div class="cd-3">
</li>
```